# Redeclared variable inside the block using let keyword and accessed before it but gives error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, javascript-scope

```
var a=10;
{
 console.log(a);
 let a =20 ;
}
```

**ReferenceError: a is not defined**

Why it is giving the reference error even a is declared using var which should have its scope inside the block too ?

Comment: Because you've removed it from scope by declaring `a` again inside the function. It can't have both. It doesn't matter if it hasn't been declared yet within the function when you log it.

Comment: Inside the block, above `let a = 20` line, it's in the *Temporal Dead Zone*. Check the duplicates for more details

Comment: Read about [hoisting here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). Someone can correct me if needed, but I think this is what causes this behavior.